# Compare Arrawy with Chart Data Series in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, charts

I have created an array which I want to add at the end of data series. However, I need to search for duplicates and add the array position only if it is **not a duplicate**. The code works but it doesn't find duplicates, just posting everything.

```
    Sub ITWORKS()
    Dim srsnum As Long
    Dim c As Range
    Dim cat() As Variant
    Set chrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Test")

    'Checking the number of dataseries in the chart
    Dim seriesCol As SeriesCollection
    Set seriesCol = chrt.Chart.SeriesCollection
    srsnum = seriesCol.Count

    ' Select worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    cat = AddDataSeriesNewCategory()

    Dim mySrs As Series


    'Adding new Data Series to Chart
    j = 1
    For Each mySrs In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Test").Chart.SeriesCollection
        For i = 0 To UBound(cat)
            Set mySrs = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Test").Chart.SeriesCollection(j)
           'Debug.Print mySrs.Name
            If mySrs.Name <> cat(i) Then
                srsnum = srsnum + 1
                seriesCol.NewSeries
                seriesCol(srsnum).Name = cat(i)
                Stop
           'Debug.Print seriesCol(srsnum).Name
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Next
        j = j + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Any errors? If so which and where? If not, what does your code actually do vs. what did you expect?

Comment: It doesn't check the duplicates. Just post everything as it goes. When the function goes two times, instead of having just one catery called 'Apple' as Data Series I have 'Apple* twice. So I believe that the problem is somewhere in the if statement.

Comment: What do you get when you `Debug.Print mySrs.Name`? Do you find the "Apple" series as expected? Can you set a breakpoint there and compare the `mySrs.Name` to `cat(i)` manually and see if they match or mismatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably that if you test for duplicate names

```
If mySrs.Name <> cat(i) Then
```

then suddenly there is an non-duplicate you add a `seriesCol.NewSeries`. You need to first test **all** series names for duplicates and if you tested **all** of them **then** you can add the series. And I think your loops need to change, the inner loop has to be the outer one.

```
For i = 0 To UBound(cat) 'loop through all cat
    Dim IsDuplicate As Boolean
    IsDuplicate = False 'initialize

    'First loop through all series and check if the name match
    For Each mySrs In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Test").Chart.SeriesCollection
        If mySrs.Name = cat(i) Then 'check for match
            IsDuplicate = True
            Exit For 'if duplicate was found we can cancel checking the rest because once a duplicate it will never change into a non-duplicate
        End If
    Next mySrs

    'if it was no duplicate add it
    If Not IsDuplicate Then
        srsnum = srsnum + 1
        seriesCol.NewSeries
        seriesCol(srsnum).Name = cat(i)
    End If
Next i
```

Check if this works.